# Conquest of the world

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

As Alexander, defeat every known player by 350BC.

Is there something tricky w/ this one? I've done it w/ no mods on a Duel sized pangea map  **Without Getting the Achievement**... Is there a minimum size to do this? Do you have to take all of their cities, or is just the capitals enough?

Comment: Would be more interesting on a huge map :-)

Comment: It's always "only conquer the capitals" because that's the domination victory.

Comment: I assume you do not play with mods and also do not have FireTuner enables. Both would prevent you from getting the achievements.

Comment: I have played w/ mods, but was not when I did this. I am unfamiliar w/ FireTuner and wasn't using it.
I did check a couple of advanced settings, specifically Quick Combat and Random Seed... would that be enough to prevent achievement acquisition?

Comment: I have just defeated my only enemy, Russia, on Pangaea, no mods, settler level, no barbarians in 1180 (47 turns) and did not get the achievement. I also made sure that the enemy had no other cities, no military units, nothing left. I think it is bugged.

Comment: I am going to replay now without any city-states. Perhaps these count as "players" in this achievement?

Comment: I added an answer to the effect of my experiment. City states seems to count as players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done it on a duel size map, and I assume you have to win a domination victory. My one enemy had only one city, so I can't say it for sure.

There is also no difficulty requirement for this achievements.

Comment: Seconded.  I completed this on a duel map and just sent a (very slow) wave of Warriors and Hoplites across the map to defeat the opponent's single city.

Answer (score 1):

Alright - I have also had this problem for a long time, and I finally got the achievement. It seems as if city states also count as players. As per my comments on the original post, I had won at 1180BC, and made sure that the enemy had no other cities and no other units. Now, without city states, the victory resulted in the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

It might need to be an "Earth" map... I'd tried several times on Pangaea maps to no avail, and just achieved it on Earth:Duel:Settler:Standard w/ no advanced settings changed.

Comment: I achieved it on a Pangea map, it's probably just bugged.